# Passing integers when floats are called for

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

If the arguments of a method call for floats to be passed, can one simply pass 10 as opposed to 10.0? I have been doing this, but often see code which specify .0 and have been wondering if there are any reasons to do so. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary, but it's a good idea to use the correct type and/or add explicit casts when you do this - more for self-documentation purposes than anything else. For literal values just specify the constant as e.g. `10.0f` - for variables just use a C-style typecast, e.g. `(float)i`.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler will generally coerce numbers to the correct type, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit to promote readability.

The constant value `10.0` is actually a `double` to most C and C++ compilers, whereas `10.0f` is a single-precision floating point number.  If you're passing a variable to a function and you know the passed type is wrong, cast it using C notation `(float)i` or C++ notation `float(i)` depending on your compiler.